# jScrollPane. TypeError: $drag[0] is undefined

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am trying to implement jScrollPane. But I am getting a number of errors in my console. They are all `TypeError: $drag[0] is undefined. maxY = trackHeight - $drag[0].offsetHeight;`

Scrollpane is recognising the div - it wraps it in jScrollPaneScrollable and removes the standard browser scrollbars - but doesn't apply it's scrollbars or allow me to scroll at all and I get the above mentioned error in my console.

My HTML:

```
<div id="homePageOffersWindow">
        <div class="homePageOffersContainer">
            <div class="homePageOfferBlock">
                <h3>HELI HIKES</h3>
                <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. </p>
                <p><strong>Save $23 per person</strong></p>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <a href="#" class="stdButton whiteBlue">MORE DETAILS</a>
            </div>
            <div class="homePageOfferBlock">
                <h3>HELI HIKES</h3>
                <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. </p>
                <p><strong>Save $23 per person</strong></p>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <a href="#" class="stdButton whiteBlue">MORE DETAILS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('#homePageOffersWindow').jScrollPane();
```

The CSS:

```
#homePageOffersWindow{height: 200px; overflow: auto}
    .homePageOffersContainer{}
    .homePageOfferBlock{margin:0 0 20px;}
    .homePageOfferBlock:last-child{margin-bottom: 0}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Using your code and adding the missing jScrollPane css it works just fine here.
http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/gbQRy/

Are you sure this is all the code you are linking?

Comment: Yep. I've tried removing all non jQuery and scrollpane scripts too in case there was a conflict anywhere

Comment: As you can see in the demo I linked it works just fine. The scrollbars are added as expected and can be scrolled without an issue. Make sure references to your script files are added at the bottom of the page unless otherwise stated for a specific script library to ensure the DOM is ready before the scripts are executed. If you have the script references at the bottom the issue is most likely related to other scripts or jQuery libraries interfering with jScrollbar. Or some other script is causing this error stopping script execution and as such jScrollbar never gets to execute to begin with.

Comment: It's strange. It is being included at the bottom in the order: jquery, scrollpane. The CSS is linked in the head but can't see why this would cause an issue. I've eliminated all other scripts.

Answer (score 1):

try to call jquery 1.4.2 instead of your jquery version
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`